# test grep output in a script

Tags: bash, grep

cat test

```
[...] tcp        0      0 172.16.32.34:46783      1xx.2xx.1xx.131:443 
ESTABLISHED 1000       2101052     18904/skype   [...]
```

I cat test if skype exists, fetch the corresponding process:

```
!/bin/bash

grep skype test 
if [ $? ]; then

k=$(grep skype test | awk '{print $(NF)}'|grep -o '[0-9]+')

echo "got skype pid"

else

echo "skype is not running";

fi    
exit 0
```

when grep finds 'skype' everything is working fine.

when not finding 'skype' we still have "got skype pid".

It looks like $? is always == 0 when running in a script. 
If I run echo $? after having run the script, I have got 0

If I do it manually, it works fine:

```
cat test 

[...] tcp        0      0 172.16.32.34:46783     
191.235.128.131:443     ESTABLISHED 1000       2101052     18904/anything    [...]

grep skype test -> no output 

echo $? -> 1 (it works !!)
```

any idea folks ?!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is this condition:

```
if [ $? ]; then
```

this will always return true because it checks if `$?` is not null which is always true since `$?` is either `0` or `1`.

You don't need `grep`, you can just do all that in `awk` itself:

```
if awk -v s='skype' -F '[/[:blank:]]' '{exit $NF!=s}' test; then
   echo "got skype pid"
else
   echo "skype is not running"
fi
```

Comment: of course that will check agains running processes, but it seems OP already has a file called `test`

Comment: thanks Anubhava. I tried [ $?==0 ] instead of [ $? ] but this does not change the issue.

Comment: You don't even need to use `$? == 0`. Just use: `if grep -q skype test; then`

Comment: thanks c4f4t0r, thanks for the tip. didnt know that command. Anyway that does not change the pb.